# KeyError: u'max_digits' with django decimal field

Tags: django, keyerror

I have the model with below fields at starting

```
class Option(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = False, blank = False)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(null = False, blank = False, editable = True)
```

At first, i designed the model with price field as `PositiveIntegerField`, but when we enter a decimal value like `5.36, 56.2314` etc., i was getting a `Keyerror : 'invalid'`

So i decided to change the field from `PositiveIntegerField` to `DecimalField` and change the price field like below

```
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 6, decimal_places = 2, null = False, blank = False)  # price in dollars
```

But when we tried to enter the decimal values like 32.56, 5.36, etc., and when tried to save the record, it was throwing me an error like below

```
u'max_digits'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/option/new/192/
Django Version: 1.5.4
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:    
u'max_digits'
Exception Location: /home/user/Envs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py in validate, line 320
```

and error in **views.py** at line `23`

```
21 if request.method == 'POST':
22        option_formset = OptionFormset(request.POST, request.FILES)
23        if option_formset.is_valid():
```

So why am i facing the `keyerror` when i changed the price from `PositiveIntegerField` to DecimalField ?, how to avoid this, any extra work need to be done, to change the field (if it already was a different type)

**forms.py**

```
class OptionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Option

OptionFormset = formset_factory(OptionForm, max_num=10, formset=RequiredFormSet)
```

Comment: Could you paste the source of "OptionFormset". It seems that it's using still the widget for PositiveIntegerField

Comment: sorry what does source means ? form?

Comment: Hm, probably you should try to debug with tracing into Django source code.

Comment: @shivakrishna: yes, the source code of the form. Thanx. I'll try it.

Comment: Could you try find . -name "*pyc" -delete or something like that ?

Comment: ooopps its an empty result